# getActivity() in onCreate() or onCreateView() (in Fragment)

Tags: android

I have a simply question.

I have a Fragment which has:

```
private Context context;
```

and I want:

```
context = getActivity();
```

So this should be in `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` and why?

Comment: Fragment is loaded under activity context so you get activity context using getActivity() in Fragment.

Comment: This is the fragment lifecycle http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png

Answer (score 2):

In `Fragment` we always use

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.application_form, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState1) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState1);
// do whatever you want
}
```